# Only get ElementsByTagName if they are in certain node

Tags: c#, .net

building a Windows Form C# app. I am trying to read an XML file, and specfically trying to get certain attributes. My code is as follows:

```
XmlNodeList elemList = readXml.GetElementsByTagName("Function");
            MessageBox.Show(elemList.Count.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
               listBox1.Items.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].Value);
            }
```

This code works great, apart from the problem that the tag  is used later in the document as a childnode of other data, in which the Name attribute is not present, thus causing an exception. How can I make it so it only reads Function tags that are children of a certain node?

EDIT:

Sample XML as follows

These are what I am trying to grab

```
      <Function ID="2" Type="Collection" Name="Left/Right" Path="page 1">
       <Step Number="0">26</Step>
       <Step Number="1">29</Step>
       <Step Number="2">23</Step>
      </Function>
```

This is where function is used in something else which I do not want to grab

```
    <Button Caption="page 2 program 6" ID="14" Icon="">
       <WindowState Visible="True" X="60" Y="60" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        <Appearance>
       <FrameStyle>None</FrameStyle>
        <ForegroundColor>Default</ForegroundColor>
       <BackgroundColor>Default</BackgroundColor>
        <BackgroundImage>None</BackgroundImage>
        <Font>Default</Font>
        </Appearance>
         <Function ID="13"/>
        <Action>Toggle</Action>
        <Intensity Adjust="False">100</Intensity>
       </Button>
```

Comment: Please post some sample xml with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HasAttribute` method. It allows you to check an XML element for a specific attribute and from there you can decide whether to reference the name object or not, thereby preventing the exception.

EDIT:

Actually, to make it even less complicated, use the `Name` property from the `XmlNode` class. Check for null and only add to the list if not null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    if (elemList[i].Name != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].Value);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: where in the code would i add it? I'm not sure how to make this check before i add to the element list.

Comment: Cheers man, and also to Hari Prasad for suggesting some similar. I cannot believe i overlooked this !

Comment: Glad to help! If this response answered your question, please indicate by clicking the check to accept the answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple `Linq to Xml`, it is more efficient.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);     
var elements = doc.Descendants("Function")
                  .Where(x=>x.Attribute("Name") !=null);
```

So your code should simplified to

```
var values = doc.Descendants("Function")
                .Where(x=>x.Attribute("Name") !=null)
                .Select(x=> (string)x.Element("Name").Value);

listBox1.Items.AddRange(values);
```

Alternatively, you could fix your code by having *null* check for attribute existence.

```
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    if (elemList[i].Attributes != null
     && elemList[i].Attributes["Name"] != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].Value);
    }
}
```